# AFNetworking POST created but blank

Tags: iphone, ios, post, afnetworking

I am building a rails-backed ios app that uses AFNetworking to POST content to a server. A user can upload a photo with a comment - and this works. I also want to have the option to let a user upload just text- this is where I am having trouble. I have one method for saving a photo and text, and another method for saving just text. The save photo method works, but the save text method creates a post but the text is null.
The save photo implementation is like this:

```
- (void)savePhotoAtLocation:(CLLocation *)location
                     withBlock:(void (^)(CGFloat))progressBlock completion:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completionBlock {

if (!self.content) self.content = @"";

NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"post[content]" : self.content,
                         @"post[lat]": @(location.coordinate.latitude),
                         @"post[lng]": @(location.coordinate.longitude)

                         };

NSURLRequest *postRequest = [[APIClient sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"                                                                               path:@"/posts" parameters:params 
    constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                                          {
                                              [formData appendPartWithFileData:self.photoData
                                                                          name:@"post[photo]"
                                                                      fileName:@""
                                                                      mimeType:@"image/png"];
                                          }];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest];
```

This method only works when there is photoData- if you don't have photoData, the app crashes.
So I am wondering what is the equivalent to a multipartFormRequest- that lets you only include a string?
This is what I have right now- which creates a post- but returns content: as well as the lat/lng params which should be returned with the current location.
This is defined in the post model

```
- (void)savePostAtLocation:(CLLocation *)location
    withBlock:(void (^)(CGFloat progress))progressBlock completion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))completionBlock {

    if (!self.content) self.content = @"";

    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"post[content]" : self.content,
                             @"post[lat]" : @(location.coordinate.latitude),
                             @"post[lng]" : @(location.coordinate.longitude)
                                  };

    NSURLRequest *postRequest = [[APIClient sharedClient]requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/posts" parameters:params];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (operation.response.statusCode == 200 || operation.response.statusCode == 201) {
            NSLog(@"Created, %@", responseObject);
            NSDictionary *updatedPost = [responseObject objectForKey:@"post"];
            [self updateFromJSON:updatedPost];
            [self notifyCreated];
            completionBlock(YES, nil);
        } else {
            completionBlock(NO, nil);
        }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        completionBlock(NO, error);
        }];

    [[APIClient sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

And in the AddPostViewController *save* calls this:

```
- (void)save:(id)sender

{
    CLLocationManager * locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 80.0f;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self getLocation];
    CLLocation * location = [locationManager location];

    Post *post = [[Post alloc] init];
    post.content = self.contentTextField.text;

    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    ProgressView *progressView = [ProgressView presentInWindow:self.view.window];
    if (location) {

    [post savePostAtLocation:self.locationManager.location withBlock:^(CGFloat progress) {
        [progressView setProgress:progress];
    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        [progressView dismiss];
        if (success) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
        }
    }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No Location");
    }
}
```

Here is the log after a post is created. As you can see the attributes are null- and shouldn't be.

```
Created, {
    post =     {
        content = "<null>";
        "created_at" = "2013-07-21T18:45:12Z";
        id = 13;
        lat = "<null>";
        lng = "<null>";

    success = 1;
}
```

So the fact that a post is created but the attributes are null makes me think that the problem is simply in the NSURLRequest- and that I am not fully implementing the AFNetworking protocol but I haven't been able to find a way to implement a post request that doesn't entail fileData. How do I make a post request that doesn't append fileData?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What actually doesn't work? What is the server expecting to receive? It really isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Wain A post is created but the parameters from the dictionary are blank. Content is null as well as lat and lng null. I'll include the log from a successful post above so you can see.

Comment: A dictionary can't contain `nil`. If you tried to set `nil` you'd get an exception. What is the server expecting to receive, is it an issue with picking up the POST parameters?

Comment: @Wain yes. I have a category implemented that returns a null value that protects against that exception because it makes it easier to figure out lat/lng problems. But yes- this is an issue of picking up post params

Comment: Hopefully your category method outputs a log when it averts the exception... So what is the server expecting to receive? Have you checked the server log? Without knowing what parameter names the server expects you can't provide the correct parameters.

Comment: @Wain I think the params are correct because I have two ways of implementing the Post model - one that includes a photo and text (and is fully functional), and the other that only has text. The params and dictionary are the same. I am just struggling to implement the proper request method - one that doesn't call for fileData..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work:
post.h

```
+ (void)createNoteAtLocation:(CLLocation *)location
                 withContent:(NSString *)content
                       block:(void (^)(Post *post))block;
```

post.m

```
+ (void)createNoteAtLocation:(CLLocation *)location
                 withContent:(NSString *)content
                       block:(void (^)(Post *post))block
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"post": @{
                                          @"lat": @(location.coordinate.latitude),
                                          @"lng": @(location.coordinate.longitude),
                                          @"content": content
                                          }
                                  };

    [[APIClient sharedClient] postPath:@"/posts" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        Post *post = [[Post alloc] initWithDictionary:responseObject];
        if (block) {
            block(post);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (block) {
            block(nil);
        }
    }];
}
```

And finally in the createPostViewController:

```
- (void)save:(id)sender

{
    CLLocationManager * locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 80.0f;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [self getLocation];
    CLLocation * location = [locationManager location];


    Post *post = [[Post alloc] init];
    post.content = self.contentTextField.text;

    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    if (location) {

        [Post createNoteAtLocation:location withContent:self.contentTextField.text block:^(Post *post) {
            NSLog(@"Block: %@", post);
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your existing method but instead of using `appendPartWithFileData:name:fileName:mimeType:` to set file data you can convert your parameters to data and add them with `appendPartWithFormData:name:`.